# deleting duplicate rows in excel and leaving the deleted cells blank

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with ~600+ rows of data and 20 columns. A lot of the values in column C (customer Numbers) and D (credit limit) are duplicates, and I would like to delete those duplicates. The problem I'm able to delete the duplicates customer numbers in Columns C using

```
=IF(C3="","",IF(COUNTIF($C2:C657,C3)=1,C3,"")
```

... but I'm not able to use same for Col D since many customers will be having same CL limits.

Is there a way to do this for each data in Col C and D in the worksheet by giving criteria as Col C? I imagine it involves "For Each...", but i don't have a lot of experience with that and haven't been able to find any other macros that can complete this task. Let me know if you need me to elaborate on what I am trying to accomplish.

Data at present:

```
Super Customer Number   Super Cust Credit Limit Super Cust Balance 
12345   7,000,000   3954758.62
12345   7,000,000   3954758.62
12345   7,000,000   3954758.62
12345   7,000,000   3954758.62
12345   7,000,000   3954758.62
123456  6,000,000   4634651.09
100136  2,000,000   681500
100131  8,000,000   9159719.01
100131  8,000,000   9159719.01
```

Data should be after running macros:

```
Super Customer Number   Super Cust Credit Limit Super Cust Balance 
12345   7,000,000   3954758.62
12345       
12345       
12345       
12345       
123456  6,000,000   4634651.09
123456  2,000,000   681500
100131  8,000,000   9159719.01
100131
```

Comment: Why `100136  2,000,000   681500` in one and `123456  2,000,000   681500` in the other?

Comment: @SunilT is your "Super" column always sorted? (eg. `12345` will always follow `12345` until a Super Change, or can it also be like `12345`, `41415`, `12345`) ??

Comment: @rawrplus super customer column will be always sorted before the report is prepared.

Comment: @Jeeped super customer numbers will be different but Super Cust Credit Limit and Super Cust Balance can be same for other customers as well

Answer (score 0):

```
 Sub KillEm
 dim c as range
 dim lastrow as long
 lastrow = cells(rows.count,3).end(xlup).row
 set c = range("c2")
 c.currentregion.sort key1:=c,key2:=c.offset(0,1)
 Do
 if c = c.offset(1,0) and c.offset(0,1)=c.offset(1,1) then
      c.offset(1,0).entirerow.clearcontents
      set c = c.offset(1,0)
 end if
 set c = c.offset(1,0)
 Loop until c.row > lastrow
```